# Swap references at build time in VS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, compact-framework, reference

I have a project that runs on both .NET and .NET CF. But it uses a 3rd party library
that will not run on both. So I end up changing the reference every time the project gets built.

Project A - References the 3rd party dll.

Project B - References A and runs .NET CF

Project C - References A and runs .NET

Is there a way to automate it?

Here is a link to that 3rd party library: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/Wikipage

Comment: What do you mean saying 'will not run both' ?

Comment: The 3rd party library has two versions. One for .NET and one for .NET CF. If I build the project with the wrong reference things go south in a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up two build configurations in your solution - one for .Net and one for .Net CF - and use conditional references to switch which version of the library is referenced.

Set up two new build configurations for `.Net` and `.Net CF` (the same as you would for debug and release configurations ie. Build -> Configuration Manager). Add both the .Net and the .Net CF 3rd party dlls as references to project A. You will then need to hand-edit the project file for project A - see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786917/is-there-a-way-to-specify-assembly-references-based-on-build-configuration-in-vis/1787075#1787075) for how to do this. Make sure you set project B to not build in the `.Net` build configuration and project C to not build in the `.Net CF` build configuration.

This enables you to build either a `.Net` output or a `.Net CF` output based on the currently selected build configuration, all within one solution, all using the same projects.

Answer (score 1):

You could make separate solutions and setup build configurations appropriately for each. You would have to maintain both solutions manually, though, from then on.

Comment: Yeah that is what I would like to avoid.

Comment: I could, however create an interface and then have two implementations. That would minimize the maintaining two projects...

Comment: According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/f032a9b7-50d5-4459-bd2f-5bfe2d6022c2, we can't expect this from MS but there may be 3rd party tools.