# MSBUILD Error MSB4025 in TeamCity build step for Visual Studio

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

When I run my TeamCity build with the only build step being of runner type Visual Studio (sln), I get the following error:

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\4978ec6ee0ade5b4\Test\Code\Test.sln(2, 1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.
```

This is on a dedicated CI server running TeamCity Professional 8.1.1 (build 29939). There are several other successfully-running builds on this server.

The odd bit is that the same build runs successfully on TeamCity on my dev machine. I followed [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19351747/1150368) to a similar question, and copied the specified folders across, but that didn't help.

I'm sure the project/solution file isn't invalid because in addition to the build running on my dev box, I have opened the solution in Visual Studio and built it there with no problems.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just fixed this.

Look inside the Test.sln file for Project or EndProject tags that aren't closed. For us, the EndProject was missing and it broke on teamcity, but no issues in Visual Studio.

Comment: There are tools for parsing .sln files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707107/library-for-parsing-visual-studio-solution-files
I used https://slntools.codeplex.com/, any of the commands will tell you what's missing from your .sln file

Comment: I also noticed you get a much more helpful error message if you try to run it with MSBuild.

Comment: Look for a XML Typing Mistake (usually outside a XML tag). Or a missing Tag. You can run it through an XML Validator.to check.

Answer (score 7):

It seems the TeamCity error message will occur for any number of root causes. In my case the problem occurred because a line inside the GlobalSection(NestedProjects) section was referring to a project Guid which didn't relate to any project defined in the Solution file.

As with the previous post I didn't have any issues building in Visual Studio. I only got a more helpful error message that allowed me to discover what the real problem was when I built using msbuild.

See https://therightjoin.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/msb4025-the-project-file-could-not-be-loaded-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-error-when-building-ssdt-project-in-teamcity for another example, and where using msbuild helped identify the true problem.

Answer (score 4):

In our case, it was a duplicate project reference in the solution file (caused by near simultaneous commits and an automatic merge).

Answer (score 2):

In our situation the problem was specifying a ToolsVersion that was not installed on that machine. (14 which VS2015 has but VS2017 does not have by default)

Comment: This solved my issue. I ended up installing the build tools version that I required

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after merging, in .sln file, it was a mismatch of lines under

```
GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution  

{6B971E15-6B61-4AA8-9B93-9639C23269C3} = {9A14E7EF-3FA1-4B9A-B413-C550B3E5AC62}

{54D14F01-D576-4DE6-9404-D21AD0DC4916} = {9A14E7EF-3FA1-4B9A-B413-C550B3E5AC62}

... (was some extra entry here )
...

 EndGlobalSection
```

section. In clear words, there were some extra lines added after merging. So, If you have merged, please compare two solution files manually. You can start with total line numbers in both files.

Answer (score 1):

In another Case

We had a blank lines - so make sure any blank lines are removed!

Hope this helps some else too!

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error with Jenkins. It turns out the root Jenkins folder was set to C:\Program Files (x86)\ and it didn't have write access to bin and obj directories.

Error:
error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid.

I launched cmd as Administrator and ran this:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\BuildBI_1\Reports\Test\ReportsTests.sln" /t:Build /p:RunOctoPack=true

And that gave me clues about not being able to write to bin and obj.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me- 
You can install [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15), make sure to select C++ tools, Windows 10 SDK and MSBuild and your set.

Comment: This solved my issue. I ended up installing the build tools version that I required

Answer (score 0):

Use `MSBuild` to identify the underlying problem:

```
$> msbuild mysolution.sln
```

Gave me this beauty with the correct **error line number**:

[image]

If msbuild cannot be accessed like that from the command line / powershell, try to find the MSBuild.exe shipped with VisualStudio, e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe`.

VisualStudio itself seems to be very "tolerant" against errors / inconsistencies in the solution file, so having it open in VS is no guarantee for the `sln` file being correct.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by updating the solution file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible problem (and resolution): I had a stray unused solution file in my repo, pointing to who-knows-where, and the MSBUILD step in my Azure DevOps pipeline was set to `**\*.sln`.